# How to use a string placeholder for the model_dir in tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering?

Tags: tensorflow, k-means

I'm using TF version 1.12 with conda and python 3.
My question concerns the model_dir value of tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering : how to use a string placeholder for the model_dir value?

Here is the context: I have pretrained KMeans in different situation, checkpoints are in different model_dir.

I want to use predictions of these pretrained models inside a graph, depending on each situation, so I need to put in this graph the KMeansClustering which can accept different model_dirs.

In the graph I defined :

```
ckpt_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
...
kmeans = KMeansClustering(5, model_dir=ckpt_ph,distance_metric='cosine')
def input_fn():
    return tf.train.limit_epochs(tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32), num_epochs=1)
centers_idx = list(kmeans.predict(input_fn,predict_keys='cluster_index',checkpoint_path=ckpt_ph,yield_single_examples=False))[0]['cluster_index']
centers_val = kmeans.cluster_centers()
...
```

And I run it with:

```
...
for ind in range(nb_cases):
    ...
    sess.run([...], feed_dict={..., ckpt_ph: km_ckpt[ind]})
...
```

Where km_ckpt is the list of pretrained KMeansClustering checkpoints pathes that I want to use for each situations.

The error that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "main.py", line 23, in main
    launch_training()
  File "main.py", line 14, in launch_training
    train_mnist.train_model()
  File "C:\Users\Denis\ML\ScatteringReconstruction\src\model\train_mnist.py", line 355, in train_model
    X_r = SR(X_tensor)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\ML\ScatteringReconstruction\src\model\train_mnist.py", line 316, in __call__
    kmeans = KMeansClustering(FLAGS.km_k, model_dir=ckpt_ph, distance_metric='cosine')
  File "C:\Users\Denis\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\factorization\python\ops\kmeans.py", line 423, in __init__
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 189, in __init__
    model_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1665, in maybe_overwrite_model_dir_and_session_config
    if model_dir:
  File "C:\Users\Denis\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 671, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

I think that the problem is that in KMeansClustering and KMeansClustering.predict, model_dir is expecting a Python bool or string, and I'm giving him a Tensor, but then I don't see hos to use pretrained KMeansClustering inside a graph.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you use a different KMeansClustering graph with a different pretrained model dir for each one? `for ind in range(nb_cases): ...kmeans = KMeansClustering(5, model_dir=km_ckpt[ind],...); ...; sess.run(...)...`

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. I would like, but in this case the graphs should not all have the name `kmeans` because at each step, the new graph will replace the older and previous graphs will be lost?

Comment: Once all kmeans graphs are pretrained, I need to use their `predict` property  several times and in various orders.

Comment: I may have found a partial answer: by setting `model_dir='%s'%ckpt_ph` I don't get error on the definition of KMeansClustering but I get one for the prediction:
`ValueError: Tensor("SR/strided_slice_2465:0", shape=(), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0) must be from the same graph as Tensor("sub:0", shape=(), dtype=int32).`
I don't know yet what to do with this..